# Question about program

Tags: debugging, memory-management

Can anybody tell me what program is this?

[image: Mystery App]

Is this for memory measurement or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's [Instruments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruments_%28application%29). It's used to monitor the performance and, as you say, memory usage of Mac and iOS apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's Xcode. (or some part of Xcode)

http://developer.apple.com/technologies/xcode.html